# Making new categorical raster selected from stack having maximum values for each pixels in R

Tags: raster, r, rasterstack

I have a raster stack having different raster layers with band names (e.g. B1, B2, B3, ….…. Bn). I need to prepare a new categorical raster with band name (for each pixels) having maximum pixel values selected from a stack.

I have used the following code:

```
library(raster) 
files <- list.files("E:/Red Panda/TIF/", pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE ) 
Raster_stack <- stack(files) 
pixelMaxBand.ras <- whiches.max(Raster_stack)
```

But I found this type of error:

> Error in .local(x, ...) : you can use only use this function for an
> object with less than 10 layers.

With “whiches.max” function for layers greater than 10, can you suggest the appropriate code?

Comment: I have a multiband raster stack and I want to find the band number of the maximum value for each pixel. For this, I have used the following code:
library(raster)
files <- list.files("E:/Red Panda/TIF/", pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE )
Raster_stack <- stack(files)
pixelMaxBand.ras <- whiches.max(Raster_stack)
But I found this type of error:
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  you can use only use this function for an object with less than 10 layers.
With “whiches.max” function for layers greater than 10, can you please suggest me the appropriate code?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the base function `which.max` to `raster::calc`. The vector length should remain constant because `raster::calc` does not remove NA's unless you pass it a function that supports an `na.rm` argument. What you are after is a simple as:

```
library(raster)

r <- do.call(raster::stack, replicate(6, 
       raster::raster(matrix(runif(1000), 100, 100))))

( rmax <- calc(r, which.max) )
```

The terra package allows you to apply `which.max` directly to the raster object. I recommend starting to move your workflows to terra as it is the eventual replacement for raster and is considerably faster with a better function interface.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(r)
( rmax <- which.max(r) )
```

Comment: Again I run the code as follows:  #Get the names of all the files with extension ".asc" of the folder
files <- list.files("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ASCII/", pattern='asc$', full.names=TRUE )
files
Raster_stack <- stack(files)
Raster_stack
names(Raster_stack)
plot(Raster_stack)

# Identify pixel-wise band with max value 
new_cat_raster <- raster::calc(Raster_stack, fun=which.max, na.rm=FALSE)      and the result is: Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function arguments? How can I remove it?

Comment: Code: new_cat_raster <- raster::calc(Raster_stack, fun=which.max, na.rm=FALSE) and the error is: Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function arguments?

Comment: @ShivaPariyar at some point the calc function has changed it's NA handling with the na.rm argument. Just omit it as, the default behavior of calc is to retain NA's so, the vector length should remain constant (see edit to my answer).

Comment: The issue here is that `which.max`  does not have a `na.rm` argument, so you should not provide it.

Comment: @Robert Hijmans Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which.max` directly

Example data

```
library(raster)
f <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s <- stack(f/2, f, f, f)
nlayers(s)
#[1] 12
# add some `NA`s
s[[12]] <- setValues(s[[12]], NA)

(r <- which.max(s))   
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 1, 6  (min, max)
```

As Jeffrey Evens pointed out, you can also do:

```
rc <- calc(s, which.max)
```

The reason that you can use `whiches.max` with no more then 9 layers (it could have been 10) is that it also returns ties:

```
(rr <- whiches.max(s[[1:9]]))
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m #+no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 47, 123456789  (min, max)
```

`47` means that layers 4 and 7 both have the maximum value.

Also note that `which.max` always ignores `NA`s:

```
which.max(c(NA, 1:5, NA, 3))
#[1] 6
```

And with `terra`:

```
library(terra)    
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(c(f, f, f, f))
x[[1:3]] <- x[[1:3]] / 2
which.max(x)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : which.max 
#min value   :         1 
#max value   :         6
```